# Deciding type information at compiletime?

Tags: typescript

I have an instance of type A or B. I want to create a single function that takes a param of either A or B and returns its wrapped argument. I.e.

```js
type A = { name: string };
type B = A[];

type DucktypedA = { // idc how this struct looks like as we can differentiate between A and B
  a: A,
};

type DucktypedB = {
  b: B,
}

function test(arg: A | B): DucktypedA | DucktypedB {
  if (arg instanceof A) {
    return { a: arg };
  } else {
    return { b: arg };
  }
}
```

Is this possible in typescript?

```
const a = { name: "me" };
const wrappedA = test(a); // --> { a: { name: "me" } }

const b = [{ name: "me" }];
const wrappedB = test(b); // --> { b: [{ name: "me" }] }
```

Answer (score 0):

`instanceof` does not work with typescript types. It can work with classes but nothing more

```
class A {}

const a = new A();

console.assert(a instanceof A)
```

You can use type guard function to bring "typechecking" into runtime realm. [Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeUB2BDAthAXFAzsAE4CWqA5lAL4DcAUKJFAEIKwDaAuvQ+NACIBXAMYBrRhAAmcRCgD0cqCUnCoACwD2AdyjA1JfAWIjgUADYaNow2ZKjo6Q1ujD0qKJJIAzLxCIRUYBJ0YGgAIwhgZwDYKDdJFjooOLwYABo6WjpeJiExCUlWWSSoMLxmDKpsr0FUYSCNdwMYAAoANzw3EABKPDalQzgkEuT-YEEidwByDGwppXc2zOra+pJG3QhCFvQiclSoAB8WXqg88T5pI7ORC8hC5BLvKBbmnb3u7sfk0ciJ9xQ6E6e2o9GSVCgEDM+Ggwx+UDG-2QpWBlCy4OWdGEjUIcTYKFmuCgACJsMTQVicRozBAAHQWcgtULbdCfGhQBRQAC0XIAfMigcjCXhSRByRCqpTULiwmx2ASsETReLuFL8NS6QymVtgC0wmyOYoefyUGUoPK0IqRWTqJxqEA)

```
function isA(v: any): v is A {
    return 'name' in v
}

function test(arg: A | B): DucktypedA | DucktypedB {
  if (isA(arg)) {
    return { a: arg };
  } else {
    return { b: arg };
  }
}
```